# Statsd Cluster Proxy

Tags: proxy, cluster-computing, graphite, statsd

I'm trying to set up a Statsd cluster with their cluster proxy. But all i found was their "official" readme file... https://github.com/etsy/statsd/blob/master/docs/cluster_proxy.md

Can someone tell me a bit more about clustering of statsd server/instances?

And by the way, is this slide of the presentation (https://speakerdeck.com/draco2003/measure-everything) correct? https://speakerd.s3.amazonaws.com/presentations/9afefbe094950130a5bd0ee022157b64/slide_21.jpg?1367417187

And how to aggregate all data into one graphite?

Thank you!